# Все маршруты ведут на главную

Tags: php, yii2

После переноса с локалхост все мапршруты ведет на главную, даже не существующие. В логах пусто. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Вот файл `.htaccess` с корня сайта:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt web/robots.txt [L]
# Все что находится в папке web, что нужно показать
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Вот с папки web:

```
RewriteBase /
# Если это папка или файл, открываем его
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# В противном случае перенаправляем на index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: ModRewrire вкл/выкл?

Comment: @КапитанФлинт включен(